# Writing Parser for Positive JSON Number w/ Decimal

Tags: parsing, haskell

Given the following definitions from Prof. Yorgey's [UPenn class](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/):

`newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }`

```
satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy p = Parser f
  where
    f [] = Nothing    -- fail on the empty input
    f (x:xs)          -- check if x satisfies the predicate
                        -- if so, return x along with the remainder
                        -- of the input (that is, xs)
        | p x       = Just (x, xs)
        | otherwise = Nothing  -- otherwise, fail
```

And the following algebraic data types:

```
type Key = String

data Json = JObj Key JValue 
            | Arr [JValue] 
            deriving Show

data JValue = N Double
              | S String
              | B Bool
              | J Json
               deriving Show
```

I wrote the following function to parse a position JSON number with a decimal point:

```
parseDecimalPoint :: Parser Char
parseDecimalPoint = satisfy (== '.')

type Whole   = Integer
type Decimal = Integer

readWholeAndDecimal :: Whole -> Decimal -> Double
readWholeAndDecimal w d = read $ (show w) ++ "." ++ (show d)

parsePositiveDecimal:: Parser JValue
parsePositiveDecimal = (\x _ y -> f x y) <$> ( 
      (oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber)) <*> parseDecimalPoint <*> 
           (zeroOrMore (satisfy isNumber)) )
  where 
    f x [] = N (read x)
    f x y  = N (-(readWholeAndDecimal (read x) (read y)))
```

However I'm getting the following compile-time error:

```
JsonParser.hs:30:25:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 -> [Char] -> JValue’
                with actual type ‘JValue’
    The lambda expression ‘\ x _ y -> f x y’ has three arguments,
    but its type ‘String -> JValue’ has only one
    In the first argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘(\ x _ y -> f x y)’
    In the expression:
      (\ x _ y -> f x y)
      <$>
        ((oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber)) <*> parseDecimalPoint
         <*> (zeroOrMore (satisfy isNumber)))

JsonParser.hs:30:49:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char -> [Char] -> String’
    Expected type: Parser (Char -> [Char] -> String)
      Actual type: Parser [Char]
    In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
      ‘(oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber))’
    In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
      ‘(oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber)) <*> parseDecimalPoint’
```

In my `parsePositiveDecimal` function, my understanding of the types are:

`(String -> Char -> String -> JValue) <$> (Parser String <*> Parser Char <*> Parser String)`

I've worked through a few examples making parsers with `<$>` and `<*>`. But I'm not entirely grokking the types.

Any help on understanding them too would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should be parenthesized as  `(\x _ y -> f x y) <$>  
      (oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber)) <*> parseDecimalPoint <*> 
           (zeroOrMore (satisfy isNumber)`.

Answer (score 2):

Cactus is correct.  I'll expand a bit on the types.

`<$> :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

Our `f` here is `Parser`, and the first argument to `<$>` has type `String -> Char -> String -> JValue`.  Remember that this can be understood as a function which takes a `String` and returns a function `Char -> String -> JValue`  So the `a` type variable is filled in with `String`.

From that, we can see that the second argument to `<$>` needs to be of type `Parser String`.  `oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber)` has that type.

Taken together, we now have:

`(\x _ y -> f x y) <$> (oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber)) :: Parser (Char -> String -> JValue)`

We've gone from a function of 3 arguments which didn't involve `Parser` at all, to a function of 2 arguments wrapped in `Parser.`  To apply this function to it's next argument, `Char`, we need:

`(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

`f` is `Parser` again, and `a` here is `Char`.  `parseDecimalPoint :: Parser Char` has the required type for the right-hand side of `<*>`.

`(\x _ y -> f x y) <$> (oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber)) <*> parseDecimalPoint :: Parser (String -> JValue)`

We do this one more time, to get:

`(\x _ y -> f x y) <$> oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber) <*> parseDecimalPoint <*> zeroOrMore (satisfy isNumber) :: Parser JValue`

I've taken advantage of knowing the precedence and associativity of the operators to remove some parentheses.  This is how I see most such code written, but perhaps Cactus's version is more clear.  Or even the fully parenthesized version, emphasizing the associativity:

`(  ((\x _ y -> f x y) <$> 
      (oneOrMore (satisfy isNumber))) 
    <*> parseDecimalPoint) 
 <*> (zeroOrMore (satisfy isNumber)) :: Parser JValue`